Fold-expression to concatenate string_views
I wanted to have a fold-expressioned function that concatenates string_views. But the code I tried didn't work. What am I doing wrong ?
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename Allocator, typename Char, typename Traits>
auto sv_concat( basic_string_view<Char, Traits> svs ... )
{
    basic_string<Char, Traits, Allocator> str;
    str.reserve( (svs.length() + ...) );
    ((str += svs), ...);
    return str;
}

This are the clang++ 18 errors:
test.cpp:14:31: error: pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs
   14 |         str.reserve( (svs.length() + ...) );
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
test.cpp:15:17: error: pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs
   15 |         ((str += svs), ...);
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^


there is no template parameter pack in your code

please do not remove includes. They are part of the code. Without them there would be other errors.

... only work with parameter packs, i.e typename ... some_types or type_name... some_values.  You do0n't have either of those.

auto sv_concat(std::basic_string_view<Char, Traits> svs ...) is in fact auto sv_concat(std::basic_string_view<Char, Traits> svs, ... ), i.e, C-ellipsis (like printf).

std::initializer_list<std::basic_string_view<Char, Traits>> seems more appropriate as argument.

@Jarod42: An initializer list wouldn't free me from delcaring it if the contained values aren't string_views themselfes, but just convertible types either.

If you drop the template; as {..} has no type, and has limited allowed deduction possible for template: Demo.

Ok, I found a solution to keep the generic type basic_string_view<>-ish with concepts:
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <span>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
    
template<typename String, typename ... Viewables>
    requires std::same_as<String, std::basic_string<typename String::value_type, typename String::traits_type, typename String::allocator_type>>
        && (std::convertible_to<Viewables, std::basic_string_view<typename String::value_type, typename String::traits_type>> && ...)
inline String sv_concat( Viewables const &... viewables )
{
    using namespace std;
    String str;
    if constexpr( sizeof ...(Viewables) )
        [&]( auto ... views )
        {
#if defined(__cpp_lib_string_resize_and_overwrite)
            str.resize_and_overwrite( (views.length() + ...), [&]( String::value_type *p, size_t n )
                {
                    auto where = span( p, n ).begin();
                    ((where = copy( views.begin(), views.end(), where )), ...);
                    return n;
                } );
#else
            str.reserve( (views.length() + ...) );
            ((str += views), ...);
#endif
        }( basic_string_view<typename String::value_type, typename String::traits_type>( viewables ) ... );
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    cout << sv_concat<string>( "hello ", "world" ) << endl;
}

With the above solution all parameters can be anything which is convertible to a string_view according to the implicitly given value_type and traits_type of the string. I think building the array is optimized away.

requires requires C++20 and so does the std::convertible_to concept. If your C++17 compiler accepted this, it must be working with extensions turned on.

Why require the first argument to be a basic_string_view if none of the others have to be? Why have to specify the type of basic_string that you want in return? Everything you need could be deduced by just figuring out the CharT of the first argument, be it a CharT*, a basic_string_view<CharT>, a basic_string<CharT> or anything else that makes sense when it comes to concatenating it into a basic_string<CharT>. The requirement for the rest of the arguments would then be that they have the same CharT. All arguments must then also be convertible into basic_string_view<CharT>.

@TedLyngmo: Look at the newer and shorter version. Now I dont't take the value_type and traits_type from the reference string_view but just from the String-type. Now I won't have to supply a string_view as the first paramter but I can take anything which can be converted to a string_:view.

Nicer, although I still thing having to supply std::string is unnecessary. I would also not restrict it to sizeof ...(Viewables) >= 1. Use if constexpr (sizeof ...(Viewables) >= 1) { ... } inside the function body instead. That way it allows for empty strings to be created when there are no arguments.

@TedLyngmo: Suplying the string is necessary to check if the Viewables ... are convertible to string_views which match the string<>-type. And no one uses tha function parameter-less, so I can leave the check for the number of Viewables.

It's not necessary as I explained in my second comment from the top. It can be deduced by checking the CharT of whatever is supplied as the first argument.

@TedLyngmo: All the parameters can be different from string_views, so I won't get any value_type or traits_type from them. So I have to take them from elsewhere, so a explicit template parameter for the string is appropriate. And I would at least need its allocator_type, and giving an allocator_type as a single template parameter would be rather strange. Show me your code ...

" I won't get any value_type..." - Not without writing a type trait for it, but it's certainly possible to get the CharT and from there deduce everything else. Supplying an allocator can be done via an overload. You only support specifying the allocator type right now which will default-instantiate it. There's no way to supply an allocator instance.

The parameters can be anything which is convertible to a string_view, f.e. a single char pointer. With your ideas the whole complexity would be worsened. My idea can adopt anything which will be convertible to a string_view in the future; you can't do that. No one actually uses his own allocator for a string.

I don't see why. The type trait to figure out what CharT an argument is using could be made rather generic. From that, testing if the actual argument is convertible to basic_string_view<CharT> is easy.

The result is a string and all three template-parameters could be taken from the supplied basic_string-type. That's more than just supplying a CharT. You're dealing with your personal aestethics.

I'm saying that you wouldn't need to supply any template parameters in the normal usecase. Not CharT either. It would be deduced, and from there, everything else would follow. Aestethics or not, it's a bit annoying to have to supply parameters when all the information can be deduced.

@TedLyngmo: And how could I deduce the parameters if there's not a common property on the input because the input could be a char-pointer as well as a basic_string ?

You write a type trait for it as I mentioned.

Yes, a hand-written type trait is the way to go. All you need is MyTrait<Viewable>::char_type as the common property. In fact, this is exactly how the standard is able to treat the raw pointer (also a non-class type, just like your case here) as an iterator. Your case is certainly simpler than the iterator case.

With a trait you don't get all properties of the destination string type. No char_traits type and no allocator_type.

A trait can handle the char_traits. I agree that there is no way to obtain the allocator type so if you need to handle custom allocator you can't use a trait.

A trait can't handle the char_traits if the parameters are pure char-pointers.

Nothing prevents you from making MyTrait<char*>::char_type whatever you like. As I already said the ability to handle non-class types are exactly why traits are used so extensively in the standard library.

@WeijunZhou: I also need a char_traits type for the string I generate. I can't be sure what that type is from the parameters.

I thought you could just use the same char type derived from the parameters, but if that is not the case and you want to make things more general and explicit, then you're right.

@EdisonvonMyosotis Here's an outline of what I had in mind. There's plenty of room for improvement since two of the traits are pretty weak, but it should show the general idea anyway - and I made it C++17 compatible since that's what you stated originally.

There is no parameter pack in your code. And I am going to address only that issue because your approach is flawed but then the code you wrote isn't far from what would be working. Variadic templates can be used to implement variadic functions, non variadic templates can not (C ellipsis aside). In a variadic template you can restrict the many types of the template to be all the same, or to be all instantiations of the same template.
Rather than std::string_view, I use some Foo with a single template argument for the example. (Because I know I will need to use partial specialization*) I use a class template bar in place of your function template.
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename ... T>
struct bar;

template <typename ...U>
struct bar<foo<U>...>
 {
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << sizeof...(U);
    }
};

Other specializations that could be added aside, bar can only be instantiated with types that are instantiations of foo.
*: The instantiation of the class template can be wrapped inside a function again. I left that out for the sake of brevity.

The other route is to do the partial specialization in a trait:
 #include <type_traits>
 template <typename T> struct is_foo : std::false_type {};
 template <typename U> struct is_foo<foo<U>> : std::true_type {};
 template <typename T> constexpr bool is_foo_v = is_foo<T>::value;

And use that to restrict bar. SFINAE because I am old-school:
template <typename ... T>
auto bar() -> std::enable_if_t< std::conjunction_v<is_foo<T>...> > 
{ std::cout << sizeof...(T);}

Live Demo
With concepts you have a nicer way to do the same, but it will in principle do the same.
